# php-zmq is not shown on phpinfo() page

Tags: php, zeromq

I am using Wamp Server on Windows and I installed zmq library. When I write php --info on console, I see that zmq is shown as intalled.

> zmq
>
> ZMQ extension => enabled
>
> ZMQ extension version => 1.1.2
>
> libzmq version => 3.2.2

But when I create a php page with phpinfo() function to show php configuration, it does not show anything about zmq. Plus, it is unable to find ZMQContext and other ZMQ classes, like ZMQSocket. I guess it's not fully installed, but I don't know what to do anymore. I have already modified both php.ini files with required info.

> C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
>
> [ZMQ]
>
> extension=php_zmq.dll
>
> ---
>
> C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini
>
> [ZMQ]
>
> extension=php_zmq.dll

Does anyone have any idea about why?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm currently having the same issue on mac osx.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old thread; however, I had the same problem and it took me time to fix the problem. The fix is to add following line in httpd.conf file

```
LoadFile "D:/xampp/php/libzmq.dll"
```