# Class ZMQContext not found

Tags: php, zeromq

I'm running web server on nginx 1.4.6 and php 5.5 inside a virtualized machine with Ubuntu 14.04 and need to install ZeroMQ extension. I have followed the instructions on [ZMQ](http://zeromq.org/area:download) (the section *To build on UNIX-like systems*), added php language binding as instructed [here](http://zeromq.org/bindings:php), compiled it against my version of php and added the line

```
extension=zmq.so
```

to `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` as well as to `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`, which are my only `.ini` files.

After restarting `nginx` and `php-fpm` the `php -i` shows following:

```
$ php -i | grep -i zmq
zmq
ZMQ extension => enabled
ZMQ extension version => @PACKAGE_VERSION@
libzmq version => 4.0.4
```

So the ZMQ module is installed in cli, but when I visit a page with `phpinfo();` I don't see the ZMQ module configuration section and when I access the page, where the code `$context = new \ZMQContext();` is invoked, I get the **error** message:

> Class 'ZMQContext' not found".

The ZMQ module is obviously loaded properly within the cli but for some reason it is not recognised in php-fpm. I have double checked that the fpm `php.ini` is loaded and that the line with extension is there.

I also have a script `push-server.php` that runs a separate websocket server in a loop with Ratchet and listens for incoming messages to be pushed to subscribers:

```
<?php
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/app/libs/Pusher/Pusher.php';

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new App\Libs\Pusher\Pusher; // my own pusher implementation

$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');
$pull->on('message', [$pusher, 'onMessageEntry']);
$pull->on('subscribe', [$pusher, 'onSubscribe']);

$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8099, '0.0.0.0');
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

After executing `php push-server.php` it runs without errors so the ZMQ module is loaded properly in cli.

I have already tried stuff suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252657/class-zmqcontext-not-found-even-though-zmq-is-installed), but no luck. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071833/php-zmq-is-not-shown-on-phpinfo-page), but focused on windows and wamp server and so far without answer.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Same problem here, still no answer...

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps you but the code I'm using (which works) looks like this: `$context = new \React\ZMQ\Context($loop);`. So the namespace has a leading backslash. Also, you said you see the module in cli but not in fpm... are you sure you are using the correct ini for fpm, and it's able to load the module? Also make sure there aren't any errors/warnings when the script with `phpinfo()` gets executed.

Comment: Adding a leading backslash to the namespace doesn't help, the `push-server.php` starts fine, because it is invoked via php cli, the problem is in my page, where I call `$context = new \ZMQContext();` and the php fpm has not the zmq loaded. There is no error when invoking `phpinfo()`, the zmq module is just not in the list of modules. I've also tried upgrading my PHP to 5.6 but still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem disappeared after upgrading PHP to 5.6, all modules load without troubles.